# Why the option button can't be selected when odf file converted into pdf with libreoffice7.2?

Tags: pdf, libreoffice

I have installed the latest libre-office version 7.2 , and wrote a fillable odt file.
The option button can be selected in libre-office,i have upload the whole sample odt file,you can download it and try.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/3e5wy3l5k1r7mh5/mytest.odt?dl=0

Convert the odt into a fillable pdf,upload the converted pdf from odt .

[image]

https://www.dropbox.com/s/olwsohhyad0lsj7/mytest.pdf?dl=0

I can't select the option `Travel by` and `Travel along` with mouse,but the check box `I accept the terms and conditions` can be selected with mouse,how to make all the options select-able?
Please download both `mytest.odt` and `mytest.pdf` to check what happens in your environment(debian11+libreoffice7.2)?

Comment: On MacOS, using the default PDF reader (called "preview"), all entries in "travel by" and "travel along" can be selected. I suspect that your issue might depend on which PDF reader you're using. Which one is it?

Comment: I can select Travel by and Travel along in Okular, both files seem ok to me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like a bug with **some** PDF viewer.

*e.g. using Okular or qpdfview, it works (both buttons and fields, all); Evince, mupdf, xreader, epdfview do not*

Which PDF viewer do you use?

Comment: I am using  adobe reader 's linux version,there is a bug in it.